# Python Set Unordered

Tags: python

In Python set is unordered, But printing the numbers, it's giving the result is ordered.

Can anyone clarify this?

set2={10,11,12,13,14}
print(set2)

O/P: {10, 11, 12, 13, 14}

Comment: I can't find the reference answer at the moment, but this has to do with the way Python hashes small integers. The set isn't actually ordered numerically.